# Python 3: Checking if a function was called on by another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In python 3, is there a way to check if another function executed a particular function? I want the computer to do something if a function was called by the itself and something else if another function called it. Here is an example:

```
def x():
    y()

def y():
    """Psuedocode --->""" 
    if function y was called by function x:
        print ("function y was called by another function")
    elif function y was not called by function x:
        print ("function y was called not called by another function")

Input ----> x()
Output ---> function y was called by another function

Input ---> y()
Output ---> function y was not called by another function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Python feature called "Inspect". It returns a list of frame records. The third element in each record is the caller name. Refer docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

```
import inspect
def x():
    print inspect.stack()[1][3]

def y():
    x()
```

Comment: Be aware that this method is fairly unreliable for production environments since it depends on the implementation of the underlying CPython.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. really helped.

Comment: Glad that I could help you :) .